# How do I fix textures in Adobe Substance 3D Stager only rendering correctly on one plane?

Tags: 3d, texture, render-settings

I've created a simple disk model with a chamfer and fillet. I'm using an Adobe substance for texturing. I'm using Adobe Substance 3D Stager (though I had this same issue Adobe Dimension, which is basically an earlier version of Stager, and also in Blender when I used the Adobe Substance importer). It seems that the texture is only displaying properly on the XZ plane. Every other face of the plane has a scrambled texture. How can I fix this?

[image: Rendered Model]

Comment: Not the right place to ask but basically you dont have a well formed UV map

Comment: I was able to figure that out, thanks! Is there an appropriate stack exchange for questions like this?

Comment: Well not really generally, but since you used blender there is ablender.SE